# How to fill gridview with result from autocompleteextender

Tags: web-services, gridview, textbox, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

Friends, I need to populate a gridview with posssible result coming from database, when I'm typing something in a textbox in my web page. For this purpose I'm using ajaxcontroltoolkit and webservice. In webservice, a method is called when I type in the textbox and it returns result, which appears as a pop up just below the textbox control. Webmethod returns an List. Is it possible to populate a gridview in the same page with the same data as in the pop up(We can see this kind of example in facebook while searching for friends). Can I bind the grid in my web page with this array of string? I can't use any post back event to populate the gridview. It has to happen as it happens for pop up.

Comment: web-service is an important aspect for this functionality, so I rolled back.